# Infer/narrow function argument from sibling property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference

I want to narrow the type of a function argument based on a sibling property. I know that existential types would help but they are not available so I'm using a helper function. I currently have this thanks to jcalz in the comments

```js
// helper function
function helper<T extends readonly unknown[]>(o: {
  choices: T;
  func: (opts: T[number]) => T[number];
}) {
  return o;
}

helper({
  choices: [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
  ], // as const
  func(o) { // should be "one" | "two" | "three", but is string
    return o;
  }
})
```

I want `o` in `func` to be of type `"one" | "two" | "three"`, so my issue is that typescript doesn't infer the choices as a tuple but as `string[]`. I can't add `as const` to `choices` because the function will be called in javascript.

I know that I could split the choices and the function into separate arguments to the helper function, but this is not possible since there will be more properties in the object. The purpose of the properties are to describe `func`, what it needs as input and what it returns.

The final goal is to have the helper function written in typescript, but used as a type annotation in javascript. Therefore I can't provide any types when calling the function or use `as const` where it is marked with a comment.

Comment: That `TupleToUnion<T>` type is using recursion to do something that TypeScript can do in one step, like `T[number]` (as long as `T` extends some type with a numeric index signature).  If you're getting `never` out then you really want `T[number]`.  If you replace that, then the issue here seems to be primarily about getting the compiler to see an array literal of string literals and infer a tuple-of-string-literal types and not `string[]`, right?  and not with siblings.  I'd suggest using `as const` if you care about that, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mpgjMN).

Comment: If you need something else, like, you can't use `as const` in a JS file (or don't want people to have to do this), then maybe [edit] the question and we can focus on that.  Let me know what you want to see here.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks! I've updated the question. I want to infer the tuple, but without the `as const`.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wOJLyW) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, this is exactly what I need! I will then wrap the strings in an object, but that works too as I've tested just now. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd like `helper()` to treat the array literal *value* `["one", "two", "three"]` as having the *type* `["one", "two", "three"]`; that is, as a  [tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) instead of as just `string[]`.  This is easy enough to do from the *caller*'s side of the function; callers can use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) like `["one", "two", "three"] as const`.  But in cases where the callers don't want to (or cannot) use a `const` assertion, it would be nice to get the function itself to do it.

I opened [microsoft/TypeScript#30680](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) a while ago asking for some easy way to do this.  Maybe it would look like:

```
// INVALID TYPESCRIPT SYNTAX, DO NOT TRY THIS
//                        vvvvv
function helper<T extends const readonly unknown[]>(o: {
    choices: T;
    func: (opts: T[number]) => T[number];
}) {
    return o;
}
```

where `const` could somehow be applied to the generic type parameter.  Unfortunately, this is not currently part of the language.

Luckily, there are tricks to get the compiler to behave somewhat similarly.

---

If you want to give the compiler a hint that it should infer literal types, you can look at [microsoft/TypeScript#10676](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/10676).  If a type parameter is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a type that includes `string`, then the compiler will tend to infer string literal types.  The same goes for `number`.  So while an unconstrained `T` (like `T extends unknown`) will infer `string` when it sees `"one"`, a constrained `T extends string` will infer `"one"`.  If you don't really want to constrain the type parameter, then you need to come up with the widest possible constraint that contains `string` and/or `number` explicitly.  You can't use [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type) since `T extends string | unknown` is immediately collapsed to `T extends unknown`.  You can however do something like

```
type Narrowable = string | number | bigint | boolean | 
  symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};
```

And then write `T extends Narrowable` instead of `T extends unknown`.  Or in your case, `T extends readonly Narrowable[]` instead of `T extends readonly unknown[]`.

---

If you want the compiler to infer tuples instead of array types, there are other tricks.  TypeScript 4.0 introduced [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types).  If `U` is an arraylike type parameter, then the compiler will tend to see `(arr: U)` and infer an unordered array type for `U`.  But if you write `(arr: [...U])` or `(arr: readonly [...U]), it will tend to infer a tuple type.

---

Combining these gives:

```
function helper<T extends readonly Narrowable[]>(o: {
    choices: readonly [...T];
    func: (opts: T[number]) => T[number];
}) {
    return o;
}
```

And you can verify that it works:

```
helper({
    choices: [
        "one",
        "two",
        "three",
    ], // as const
    func(o) { // "one" | "two" | "three"
        return o;
    }
})
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Btw, nice suggestion `Const contexts for generic type inference\`