# Infer narrow type from parent object referencing itself in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-inference, narrowing

I would like to constrain a parameter type of a callback function that is inside an object like this:

```js
makeObj({
  items: [
    {
      value: "foo",
      func(items) {}
    },
    {
      value: "bar",
      func(items) {}
    }
  ]
});
```

I want to constrain the parameter `items` of `func` to `"foo" | "bar"`. The values of `value` can be any string though.

I already have this, but it obviously doesn't work:

```js
interface MyObject<T extends string, Values extends readonly MyObject<T, Values>[]> {
  value: T;
  func: (items: Values) => void;
}
interface Items<T extends string, Data extends readonly MyObject<T, Data>[]> {
  items: readonly [...Data];
}
function makeObj<T extends string, Data extends readonly MyObject<T, Data>[]>(opt: Items<T, Data>) {
  return opt;
}

makeObj({
  items: [
    {
      value: "foo",
      func(items) {}
/* Error on "func":
Type '(items: MyObject<string, unknown>) => void' is not assignable to type '(items: unknown) => void'.
  Types of parameters 'items' and 'items' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'MyObject<string, unknown>'.
*/
    },
    {
      value: "bar",
      func(items) {} // same error on "func"
    }
  ]
});
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMAHgBVkIAPSEAEwGdk6wpQBzAGmQDU4AbAVwgNK1emix4CxEpx4ChAPgXIA3gFgAUMmQA3PoIBcyEgG5N2mPxAIjACmCQAtnSNzBdAJTIAvMp0B7YBozDQBfTVBIWEQUAEknOlJyKghaBiYWEA5kABE4MDhk0QYoCDgafxBedHEcfEJSTjyCgG0QfkdsaABdBRbe1XNkBwhnI1LyyurkFoA6eea4bpDwjUtrMGBK5Ec4AGsIOqSRVLEMtib8wpO05AmKqpqMOqlG3Ku2jq6oXv6FW38AAcwEZ4qNEjJ3gUFF51Fo7hAwPwoCBkECwCtNJpdgc6rY4doRmMZkNtATtBS9PIjAAiGD+fw09ikinrBD2BKw1YU5ChZnwsks7RUwzIGnYOBQJlC5Bsjngrks7nIbqaUIeEJAA)

---

Some background info:
I'm writing a program that has some "actions" defined. Each action is a function in an object to describe the function (give it a name, description, input type, output type, secondary input type). The secondary input relies on user provided data. Each item of this data has a name and defined type. Its value is provided by the end user. Depending on the value of other items an item can be displayed to the user or not. This last part is controlled by the callback function in question.
I have all this already set up with narrow type inference to not make any mistakes while writing each action but this narrow type inference breaks down regardless of which type the callback function has. Either because it can't infer the narrow type anymore, or because I get a type error (e.g. when I use `object` as type for the parameter (I ultimately want to use an object as the parameter, not just a string)).
This narrow type inference works like this: [typescript - Infer/narrow function argument from sibling property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70994814/10362619)

---

**Edit:**

I would like a solution where I don't have the type embedded in the function parameter but as an interface/type that I can reference like:

```js
interface Magic<MagicParam> {
  items: MagicParam;
}
makeObj<MagicParam>(opt: Magic<MagicParam>) {
  return opt;
}
```

`Magic` can be an interface or type and can have any number of type parameters. `makeObj` too can have any number of type parameters.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wQ5vVw) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer; otherwise what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes. That's exactly it. Thank you!

Comment: How could I also make an interface out of this with a similar structure like in this question?

Comment: Is that a followup question or is it a requirement for the current question?

Comment: @jcalz That is a requirement

Comment: Ah, then could you [edit] the question to specify that?  And I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for, so could you elaborate (in the question)?  Maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/w24nrm) suffices? Not sure.

Comment: So then does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAjAZW) work for you?

Comment: @jcalz yes. That counts. I will then need to somehow make it work with what I already have with all the stuff around it.

Comment: And I assume that's *not* a requirement for the question, right?  I just want to make sure that you agree my approach does answer the question as asked before I spend time writing up an explanation.

Comment: @jcalz Well, ultimately I want to infer a lot of stuff from the properties that describe the function (="action" as I call it above). I've tried your approach in my code but haven't got it to work yet. But this is not in the scope of this question. I probably also can't make a new question with my whole code since it is messy and way too much... So yes, your assumption is correct! I was just thinking out loud.

Comment: Okay, one more thing; I simplified my solution to [this](https://tsplay.dev/wjkg7N).  Could you make sure that still answers your question as asked?

Comment: @jcalz Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `makeObj()` function could be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) corresponding to the `value` properties of the function parameter's `items` property.  If we call that generic type parameter `K`, and if you pass in, for example, `{items: [{value: "x"},{value: "y"},{value: "z"}]}` (ignoring `func` for now), then `K` should be the `"x" | "y" | "z"`

Then you can express the argument to `makeObj()` in terms of `K`. If we call that type `Opt<K>`, we can write it like this:

```
interface Opt<K extends string> {
  items: Array<{ value: K, func: (items: K) => void }>
}
```

That means, given `K` of `value` properties, we want the `items` property of `Opt<K>` to be an array, where the elements of the array are objects with a `value` property of type `K`, and a `func` callback property whose input is type `K`.

Let's make sure that's what you want, by evaluating `Opt<"foo" | "bar">` (and using [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types) and a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to coax the compiler into displaying details of the structure):

```
type Test = Opt<"foo" | "bar"> extends
  infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never 

/* type Test = {
    items: {
        value: "foo" | "bar";
        func: (items: "foo" | "bar") => void;
    }[];
} */
```

Looks good.

---

Anyway, as mentioned above, `makeObj` will be generic in `K` and take a parameter of type `Opt<K>`:

```
function makeObj<K extends string>(opt: Opt<K>) {
  return opt;
}
```

And let's see if it works:

```
const obj = makeObj({
  items: [
    {
      value: "foo",
      func(items) {
        // (parameter) items: "foo" | "bar"
      }
    },
    {
      value: "bar",
      func(items) {
        // (parameter) items: "foo" | "bar"
      }
    }
  ]
});
// const obj: Opt<"foo" | "bar">
```

Looks good too.  The compiler infers that `K` is `"foo" | "bar"`, and then [contextually types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the `items` callback parameters of the `func` property to also be `"foo" | "bar"`.  And the `obj` that comes out is of the desired `Opt<"foo" | "bar">` type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPIAcwB4DSyIAekIAJgM7JlhSgDmAfMgN4CwAUMssJALZkBcyAIJQocAJ5YmyAG5wANgFcIgnABpkMRSASCAFNwh9VASmQBeRjID2wEsgC+9dg-bsw49CgAqEKhbRMLAAiGGtrYOQAH2RggCM4KGDGQmJydk5QGGg0ZAB+ZmQAbTxQZABrCHFrGDQAXUFUErrHZEEQCBloNzYAegAqZA8vZF9-c2YMzi5eAUmOacW5JRVYsIjo2ISkgG4pxc4tHX1DYzXwyJj4xOCzS1lbEj2FzgciuueHZH7enqOEMDAawgZA8OCVVBxABWuHwRAgpAoVBoIAYemsmEaQRw9DMrAWUAgYEUUBBGLAnx6CGB-ms0ICYIh0L0+Mys0ERX28wOsgUykEoQuai5h20CAMszxIumvV6yD06EScB4ROgZlOc0FGyu22C0tcL0cwsNrIOy35Wxuxp5-wlRjIUsNi1l8sVYhVkCg6vZ521lqS+q5Bs4dRcJmeLupIFp0Kx2C1l39yR67CAA)